# Correct way to use typing in Python 3.8+ for unpacked arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-typing

Please consider the following example in Python 3.8+.
Assume a function which gets any number of arguments, all of the same type. For example

```
def fun(*foos):
    for foo in foos:
        foo.do_something()
```

I would like to add typing for the `foos` argument, for this reason assume that all arguments are of the same type `foo_type`. What is the correct way for typing?

For me the following would be the obvious typing:

```
from typing import Tuple

def fun(*foos: Tuple[foo_type]) -> None:
    for foo in foos:
        foo.do_something()
```

My IDE (CLion) suggest:

```
def fun(*foos: foo_type) -> None:
    for foo in foos:
        foo.do_something()
```

Which way of typing for the `foos` argument is correct, and why?

Comment: Are you asking for the correct way of doing function annotations?

Comment: I can't confirm it, but it's incorrect to return `NoReturn` from the annotation. `NoReturn` should be used to annotate the return type of the function which end with raise Exception.

Comment: @MechanicPig Thanks fr pointing that out! I Will adjust the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what prompted the question, the answer is (as your IDE already told you):

```
def fun(*foos: foo_type) -> NoReturn:
    for foo in foos:
        foo.do_something()
```

If you instead had something like this:

```
def fun(foos: Tuple[foo_type]) -> NoReturn:
    for foo in foos:
        foo.do_something()
```

That would work as well, but of course that would require calling the function with an actual tuple of `foo_type` elements.

In `fun(*foos: foo_type)`, the unpacked `foos` is defined to be of `foo_type`, which is what you want. If you do this instead:

```
def fun(*foos: Tuple[foo_type]) -> NoReturn:
    for foo in foos:
        foo.do_something()
```

Then you'll get errors, since a tuple doesn't have a `do_something()` (unless you give it one), but you'll still get type hints.